# difference between type:4 or type:5 and type:[4 TO 5]

Tags: solr

when I query solr

- using `q` values `my_type:4` I got `numFound: 94`
- using `q` values `my_type:5` I got `numFound: 0`
- using `q` values `my_type:5 or my_type:4` I got `numFound: 98`
- using `q` values `my_type:[4 TO 5]` I got `numFound: 94`

In the 3rd query why I found 98 results ?

some info:

**all other paramter are default**

Answer (score 1):

It's probably searching for the value `or` in the default field as well in your third example. The boolean operator is `OR` (in caps).

So the third example retrieves all documents with `my_type:5`, `my_type:4` or `or` somewhere in the default field.